# set a column to copy a column from another table (on condition)

Tags: mysql, sql

What I currently have is:

```
UPDATE card, records
IF(records.date_returned == null) THEN SET
card.last_seen = records.date_loaned
ELSE SET card.last_seen = records.date_returned
WHERE card.card_no = records.card_no
```

A little background-- the table records has two columns-- date_loaned and date_returned, with date_returned set as null by default. I was wondering whether its possible to change the last_seen column in temp_card to date_returned when it gets updated

Pretty sure its impossible, but I guess I'm trying my luck!

I was kinda hoping it to be automatic (e.g. when records get updated, this triggers the last_seen to change).

Comment: Use a `trigger`, on an update event

Comment: You want the column to be updated as soon as some other column gets updated, that is you want an event to be triggered on the update of the primary column..http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/create-trigger.html

Comment: @SashiKant
Well now I've got this but it doesnt seem to work :s:

CREATE TRIGGER insert_records AFTER UPDATE ON records
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
UPDATE card, records SET card.last_seen = records.date_returned
WHERE records.date_returned != null
AND card.card_no = records.card_no

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try like this..

```
Update  Card A INNER JOIN Record B ON (A.card_no =B.card_no) SET A.last_seen =(
                           Case WHEN B.date_returned==null
                           then B.date_loaned 
                           Else B.date_returned
                           End
                          )
```

Comment: Thank you for responding! However I got an error like
" You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ')' at line 8" And it's just the worst kind of error. Since you don't actually know whats wrong! D:

Comment: Ah it works! However I was kinda hoping it to be automatic (e.g. when i update table 'Record', column 'last_seen' would auto change accordingly. It works beautifully though, if I don't get any other answers I'll accept this as the right one!

Comment: Yes, I'm currently trying to get this to work:


CREATE TRIGGER insert_records
AFTER UPDATE ON records
FOR EACH ROW BEGIN

Update  temp_card A
INNER JOIN loan_records B
ON (A.card_no =B.card_no)
SET A.last_seen =(
                           Case WHEN B.date_returned=null
                           then B.date_loaned 
                           Else B.date_returned
                           END
                          )

Comment: It isnt, unfortunately. im getting "You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '' at line 13", with line 13 being ")"

Answer (score 0):

How about using `CASE` like

```
UPDATE card, records
SET
 card= CASE records.date_returned == null 
 THEN  card.last_seen = records.date_loaned
 ELSE SET card.last_seen = records.date_returned
WHERE card.card_no = records.card_no
```